# Чем представлена информация, входящая в процессор и выходящая из него?

Tags: архитектура, процессор, электроника

Чем представлена информация, входящая в процессор и выходящая из него? (Ток какого логического вида?)

Comment: Смысле чем? Напряжением/током на ножках

Comment: Если считать процессор функцией "and" 2 переменных a,b то подав напряжение на клеммы а b можно получить результат

Comment: Процессор тоже самый and только переменных и функции побольше

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l7rce6IQDWs - серия видео про сборку видеокарты. В общем-то, процессор будет как-то аналогично, может быть даже есть где-то на канале.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Современные микросхемы общаются друг с другом при помощи *напряжения* определенного логического уровня (как правило, равного или немного меньшего напряжению питания - VCC).

За логическую единицу принимают напряжение выше половины VCC, за логический ноль -  меньше 0.7 вольта.

Так как современный процессор является высокоинтегрированным устройством, общение с остальной переферией происходит по разным электрическим стандартам - это могут быть, например, дифференциальные пары шины PCI-E.

Comment: Напряжений питания у современных процессоров несколько: основное или Core и дополнительные, например, для питания буферов ввода-вывода.